# How to wrap every second content element?

Tags: typo3

I have my content part on a website:

```
page.10.marks.PAGE_CONTENT < styles.content.get
```

styled with the `css_styled_content` static template.

Now I want to wrap every second `text-content-element` (and not headers) in this subpart?

Is this possible? I have tried this:

```
page.10.marks.PAGE_CONTENT.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.marks.PAGE_CONTENT.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  key.field = CType

  text = TEXT
  text.split {
    cObjNum = 1 || 2
    1.current = 1
    1.wrap = <div class="test1">|</div>
    2.current = 1
    2.wrap = <div class="test2">|</div>
  }
}
```

but it does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put a counter into the setup of the text cObject, since the split won't work due to a missing token. Something similar to this snippet should do the job:

```
tt_content.text {
  5 = LOAD_REGISTER
  5 {
    textcounter.stdWrap.dataWrap = {register:textcounter} + 1
    textcounter.prioriCalc = 1
  }
  stdWrap.outerWrap = <div class="blah">|</div>
  stdWrap.outerWrap {
    if.isFalse {
      stdWrap.dataWrap = {register:textcounter}%2
      prioriCalc = 1
    }
  }
}
```